# Average number of rolls before going broke

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a difficult probability question to resolve.

Say you have 2 chances to roll a dice. If you roll a 6, you're awarded 2 additional rolls. You can receive infinite number of additional 2 rolls every time you roll a 6.

Let X be the average number of rolls.
The chance of rolling a 6 is 1/6 = 16.67%.
Then to calculate X: (my calculation, it may be wrong)

X = 2*(1-16.67%)^2 + 4*(1-16.67%)^3*(16.67%) + 6*(1-16.67%)^4*(16.67%)^2 + 8*(1-16.67%)^5*(16.67%)^3 + ...

How do you determine the exact value of X?

Many thanks in advance for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ is the number of rolls left before a given roll, after the roll, there are either $n-1$ or $n+1$ rolls left, with respective probabilities $p=\frac56$ and $1-p=\frac16$. One asks for the mean number of rolls $X_2$ starting from $2$ rolls left.

For every $n$, the mean number of rolls $X_n$ starting from $n$ rolls left is $n$ times the mean number of rolls $X_1$ starting from $1$ roll left. Furthermore, the usual one-step analysis starting from $1$ roll left yields $$X_1=1+(1-p)X_2+pX_0,$$ that is, $X_1=1/(2p-1)$. Finally, $X_2=2X_1=2/(2p-1)=3$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However I'm looking for a more general formula that can help me solve all similar problems, hope you can help me out.
If the chance of an event happening is X, which results in Y attempts to re-trigger the event, then the average amount of attempts Z:
Z = 1*(1-X) + (1+Y)*(1-X)^Y*X + (1+2Y)*(1-x)^(2Y-1)*X^2 + (1+3Y)*(1-X)^(3Y-2)*X^3 + ...
I hope I made it clear enough.

Comment: Unless one is a mindreader, one cannot guess that you are after the solution of a more general question than the one you stated here. When you will ask a new question dedicated to this more general problem, please specify "similar" in "all similar problems",

Comment: Sorry I mistakenly sent my previous comment unfinished. Please check it again and see if you can help me out, thanks!

Comment: Same comment applies: IF other question THEN new post.

Comment: I've posted a similar question here:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757681/formula-needed-for-calculating-probability-of-recurring-events